# Multiply elements in an array in specific positions? (the first element with the last element etc)

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an array {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and I want to multiply the first element with the last, the second element with the second to last etc and then calculate the sum. So I would multiply 1 with 5, 1 with 4, and 2 with 3 so that the sum would be 15.

This is the code I have so far but it multiplies all of the elements with each other so the sum is 120 instead of 15. Any advice on how I could change it? Do I have to split up the array first before I start multiplying the elements with each other?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] array = new int [] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum = sum * array[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Comment: What if the array has an odd number of values?

Comment: Why is the `sum = 1`? Shouldn't it be equal to 0?

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the array from the beginning (i=0) and the end (j=array.length-1) and multiply the items at these indices as follows:

```
int [] array = new int [] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0, j = array.length-1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
    sum += array[i] * array[j];
}
System.out.println(sum); //15
```

In case of an odd number of items and you want to count the middle once without multiplying it by itself (use above solution if not):

```
int [] array = new int [] {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0, j = array.length-1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
    sum += (i!=j) ? array[i] * array[j] : array[i];
}
System.out.println(sum); //17
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are multiplying every element in the array. You have to first multiply the pair of numbers, and then add the result to the sum.

Example code:

```
int [] array = new int [] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int sum = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i]*array[array.length-i-1];    //multiplies the first and last, second first and second last etc.
}
sum /= 2;    //we have the double of the sum because we added array[0]*array[length-1] and array[length-1]*array[0]
```

Or, if you don't want to divide the result:

```
int [] array = new int [] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int sum = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++) {
    sum += array[i]*array[array.length-i-1];
}
```

If the array's length is odd and you want to multiply the central value with itself, include this part:

```
if(array.length%2==1){
    sum+=array[array.length/2+1]*array[array.length/2+1];
}
```

Comment: Instead of dividing by 2, it would be a lot better to just stop halfway through the array.

Comment: You could make the end of for loop `array.length / 2` to speed it up.

Comment: It would be, but I sometimes favour *readable* code over *optimized* code. Since OP is probably a beginnger, it is easier for him to understand this code.

Comment: @AP11 length/2 would be problematic with odd values, and OP didn't clarify whether he wanted to multiply that or not.

Comment: @tibetiroka It would work fine for `i < (array.length+1)/2`, this works for even and odd array length.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
int[] a = {1,1,2,3,4,5};
```

first, initialize sum to `0` or if an odd length array, to the middle element

```
int sum = a.length % 2 == 0 ? 0 : a[a.length/2];
```

Then simply multiply the values from each side, stopping halfway thru taking the sums.  `a.length>>1` divides by 2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length>>1; i++) {
    sum += a[i]*a[a.length-i-1];

}
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
15
```

Note the if the number of elements is odd, the middle element will not be multiplied by anything.  If you want it to be multiplied by itself, you can just square it when you initialize `sum`.